# How do I increase the queue length in IIS's default app pool via command line?

Tags: iis-7, exchange-2010, application-pools, threads

I have a farm of IIS servers running Exchange and we are getting this error in HTTP Error:

```
HTTP/1.1 POST /ews/exchange.asmx - 1 Connection_Dropped_List_Full MSExchangeServicesAppPool
```

The advice from MSFT is to increase the app pool queue length from 1,000 to 10,000

How do I change IIS's MSExchangeServicesAppPool to a new value via the command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax can be found on IIS.NET [site](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#Working).

To change the queue length you would have to enter:

```
appcmd.exe set APPPOOL "DefaultAppPool" /add.queueLength:10000
```

in your case:

```
appcmd.exe set APPPOOL "MSExchangeServicesAppPool" /add.queueLength:10000
```

You can list the current configuration settings with:

```
appcmd.exe list APPPOOL "MSExchangeServicesAppPool" /text:*
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a way to test this right now, so this might not work. That said you might be able to change this using appcmd (http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) to change the queue length - it's in applicationHost.config (http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add)

for example

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD set apppool "MyAppPool" /add.queueLength 10000
```

Comment: Nearly got it right.